# Creating a regular expression for the following language

Tags: computer-science, regular-expressions

I have having a problem with creating regular expressions for languages which have non containment claims.

the alphabet is the set of 0 and 1
$F=\{w|w$ doesn't contain the substring $110\}$

How would think about solving these kind of problems?. Is there a cookbook for this?